# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when loading topaz dll in OSGI environement

Tags: java, dll, osgi, topaz-signatures

i'm trying to load a dll in an equinox osgi environement using System.load() ,
the path to the dll file is correct but i always get java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError .
 i managed to load the dll when it is placed in System32 folder.
using : System.loadLibrary().

the dll works just fine when i experiment with a plain java main class , there's no need to programmaticaly load the dll since eclipse does it .

is there anything specific to OSGI that prevents me from loading my DLL ?

Answer (score 0):

any chance that your JVM is loading the dll twice? That would also cause an UnsatisfiedLinkError on the second try.